# How to invoke a C# method in JS from an MAUI WebView and vice-versa

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin, interop, maui

I want to call a method in Javascript that invokes C# code in an MAUI WebView and vice-versa, I cannot find any documentation on this.

I have looked at the [following issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6446) on github but it did not help me.

How do I do such interop?

Comment: Have you had a look at this question: [JS/.NET interact on MAUI WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73217992/js-net-interact-on-maui-webview)? Without having dealt with WebView myself, it seems like your issue could be similar?

Comment: @noel not very helpful thread

Comment: I finally found it. The link has an answer on how to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75182298/16307914

Comment: @BerkAyvaz good one, but it feels more like a hack