# .NET MAUI webview view actual HTML

Tags: c#, .net, webview, maui

Is it possible to retrieve the HTML a .NET MAUI WebView is currently displaying?
If so, how?
Unfortunately, I can't find anything on it inside the official documentation.

[.NET MAUI WebView documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview?view=net-maui-7.0&pivots=devices-android)

I am trying to retrieve the currently displayed HTML as a string, after a JavaScript event changed the HTML body content, to read out some meta-data.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can access it directly (like with WebView2). However you can [call Javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview?view=net-maui-7.0&pivots=devices-android#invoke-javascript), which have access to the HTML :

```
string result = await webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync($"document.documentElement.innerHTML");
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use **Navigated** event to detect if page changes:

In .xaml,

```
<WebView x:Name="webview" ... Navigated="webview_Navigated" />
```

In .cs, implement Event Handler

```
async void webview_Navigated(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    var webView = sender as WebView;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    // Get the html
    var html = await client.GetStringAsync((webView.Source as UrlWebViewSource).Url);
    }
```

Furthermore, you may want JS/C# interaction on MAUI WebView. You could refer to this SO issue: [JS/.NET interact on MAUI WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73217992/js-net-interact-on-maui-webview/75182298#75182298).

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the tip with the HttpClient.
Unfortunately, WebView does not register the Navigated event on most javascript interactions that are relevant for me.
But I think I'll find a workaround for that.

Comment: If you find a workaround, you could share your solution as an answer if possible. That may help others with same issue.

Comment: I will definitely do that, I haven't come around to trying out the suggestions unfortunately.

Comment: Navigated event only detect different pages load and that's not for JavaScript interactions. I also google this for native but also in vain. Probably Maui WebView cannot detect JavaScript change for an uncustomized webpage.