# .NET MAUI: How to call c# app function from javascript

Tags: javascript, maui

Is it possible to call a function of an Android/IOS app from an HTML page running in a MAUI Webview (inside the same app) via Javascript?
If so, an example would be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS/.NET interact on MAUI WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73217992/js-net-interact-on-maui-webview)