# MAUI create a webview and navigate to a url and listen all web socket message

Tags: c#, webview, maui

1. create a webview from MAUI,
2. the webview navigate to a url, it will connect to a socket server automaticly.
3. listen to all incoming or outcoming websocket messages.

Q: How to capture the websocket messages? I haven't found any document for this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did this answer help? [JS/.NET interact on MAUI WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73217992/js-net-interact-on-maui-webview). Or you may invoke native code.