# MAUI CORS ERROR while using HtmlWebViewSource

Tags: c#, html, .net, webview, maui

I have Problem with retrieving current URL of WebView control.

I want to achieve "browser tabs" effect, so the user can click on tab on header and switch between multiple view of the website.

I can't use multiple WebViews since user need to log in in each tab separately. (I wanted to share cookie and sessions between webViews bug failed.)

Now I'm tying use HtmlWebViewSource like this :

```
private async void InitializeWebView()
{
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedTab.WebSource))
        {
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(_selectedTab.CurrentUri);
            string webSource = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            _selectedTab.WebSource = webSource;
        }

        HtmlWebViewSource htmlWebViewSource = new()
        { 
            Html = _selectedTab.WebSource, 
            BaseUrl = _selectedTab.CurrentUri.AbsoluteUri
        };

        await Application.Current.Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(() =>
        {
            WebView5.Source = htmlWebViewSource;
        });

}
```

My Idea is so i can save current state as html string and switch this html depend which tab user will select but I have huge problem with CORS.
Accordingly console my location href is : "about:blank" which is frustrating since i ma ensured that baseUrl setted properly.

I don't understand why location href is empty or hove, I suppose to use WebView. I clearly see that WebView can open another windows if I click middle mouse button, but I don't understand how to handle it manually or any documentation related to this topic.

Comment: Which platform are you testing your MAUI project on, and which MAUI version are you using?

Comment: Windows10. .net-8. Not sure what you mean by maui version?

Comment: Do you mean that the log message in your VS displayed "about:blank" when the web view changed?

Comment: No, I mean that in imbedded web browser of WebView MAUI return about:blank in console on "document.location" no matter if i setting baseUrl or no.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can help me understand your problem better.

Comment: https://github.com/IgorMarkiv/MAUI_CORS_ERROR_reprodiction.git

Comment: Why not you just set url to MyWebView.Sorce, like: `Button button = (Button)sender; 
string url = button.CommandParameter.ToString(); 
try 
{ 
MyWebView.Source = url;
} ......`

Comment: Because I need HTML  to preserve current state in many tabs including filled forms, inputs, interactive elements values in js, cookies etc, just settings source is not enough.

Comment: Which platform do you want to achieve the function on?

Comment: I posted repo, this repo contains platform and reproduced issues. 
Basically i talk about MAUI windows but off course this issues must be fixed on all platforms supported with webView.

Comment: I tried to run your sample, and when the code ran to try{} catch{} in MainPage.xaml.cs, an exception ( System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'The SSL connection could not be established') occurred. Have you met this exception?

Comment: No, I don't have such an error, but you can try use own url for webViews

Comment: what do you mean about the "href"? After I clicked the button, the website displayed, then I right-clicked the WebView and selected the **Inspect**, I found `<base href="https://appdir/">` in html code. Do you mean your href here is null?

Comment: Well, I mean if you type "document.location.href" you will get "about/blank" but I think your notice also related to this issue. My goal is to set base URL correct so all js/fetches/media request would work.

Comment: This link maybe helpful for you :[JS/.NET interact on MAUI WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73217992/js-net-interact-on-maui-webview)